# What is the appropriate way to insert identity column manually?

Tags: sql

If I want to migrate customer data from another database, for example:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT TCustomer ON
GO
INSERT INTO TCustomer
    (IDCustomer,UnitHolderIDNo,FullName,ExternalUnitHolder)
SELECT
    IDCustomer = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY STC.UnitHolderIDNo ASC) --is there a better method?
    ,UnitHolderIDNo = STC.UnitHolderIDNo
    ,FullName = STC.FullName2
    ,ExternalUnitHolder = STC.ExternalUnitHolder
FROM
    SIAR.dbo.TCustomer STC
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT TCustomer OFF
```

Edit : I want to know is there a better method besides using row_number()? because if I don't migrate all the records of the table, there will be some skipped number isn't it?

Comment: I've already put <!-- language-all: lang-sql -->, but I don't know how it works

Comment: what's the issue with existing one?

Comment: I've fixed formatting for you. ;) Can you provide more details about your problem? E.g. what you are trying to do and why your attempt is not what you want.

Comment: DBMS do not care for gaps in auto increment columns.

Comment: Why don't you use an autoinc id? Do you already have data and a customer id on the destination table? And on the source table? Are there conflicts in the ids between the two tables? Please provide more details.

Comment: no, there are no data in destination table and there are no id in the source table. From what I know, SQL cannot autoinc if the wanna-be-inserted records are from select statements.

Comment: As Frazz said - why not let the existing `IDENTITY` spec handle the ID's for you? You can always order your `SELECT` by `UnitHolderIDNo` if that's what is important.

Comment: Inserting data from a SELECT had no relevance to how or whether auto increment fields work.  If you tried that and it failed then you should post that SQL and the error, asking how to fix that *(rather than us trying to fix your work-around fit something that should work.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah I see what you want now.

```
INSERT INTO TCustomer
    (UnitHolderIDNo,FullName,ExternalUnitHolder)
SELECT
    UnitHolderIDNo = STC.UnitHolderIDNo
    ,FullName = STC.FullName2
    ,ExternalUnitHolder = STC.ExternalUnitHolder
FROM
    SIAR.dbo.TCustomer STC
```

That's it. Just don't specify the auto incrementing column and let it create the ID for you. You can add `ORDER BY UnitHolderIDNo` if you need to.

Comment: well, I'm pretty sure I've try this out, but now it works. -.-, it seems my memory fails me. Thanks, the data-migration will be easier now.

Comment: No worries. We all have days like that!